# What is the asymptotic running time of the following piece of code?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

What is the asymptotic running time of the following piece of code?

```
if (N % 2 == 0) // N is even
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i = i+1)
   for (int j = 0; j < N; j = j+1)
      A[i] = j;
else // N is odd
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i = i+1)
   A[i] = i;
```

If N is even we see the running time is O(n^2), when N is odd the running time is O(n). But I can't determine what the asymptotic running time is.

The possible answers are:

- ~ O(n)
- ~ O(n^2)
- ~ O(N * sqrt(N))
- ~ O(n log n)

Comment: **Hint:** big O is an upper bound.

Comment: For what it's worth, if the question doesn't specify a tight bound, you can always just pick the largest answer and it will technically be correct for big-O.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a simple function you can use to asymptotically tightly bound the runtime. As you noted, the runtime oscillates between linear and quadratic at each step. You can say that the runtime is O(n<sup>2</sup>) and Ω(n), but without defining a piecewise function you can't give a Θ bound here.

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to bump?

Comment: Theta(n^{3/2+((-1)^n)/2})